# Could not build Objective-C module 'UIKit'

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, uikit, uicolor

Everything was working fine and now all of a sudden I get this error message and cannot not build my app anymore on my iPhone. Building it in the simulator works, but not in the iPhone.

```
#import <UIKit/UIColor.h>
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIColor.h:13:2: error: file '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/1ICTC4QF5R9QK/CoreImage-3096MN6AT838P.pcm' is not a valid precompiled module file
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
 ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'UIKit'
```

This is the error message I am getting. I have already cleared the build folder, restarted my mac.
What else can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: try deleting your derived data folder manually. there are many answers here about "could not build module x" problems.

Comment: @johnelemans I had a second DerivedData folder with the same name somehow. I deleted the folder and that worked. But now my app is stuck at the launch screen and does not go further. Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: show code my friend.

Comment: After restarting everything is working now. Who knows what caused the problem ..